# how to use DDE server

Tags: delphi, dde

Can I get a little code example to use DDE as a server? I know how to use the client part, but can't figure setting up my app to act as a server and receive data.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look in your Delphi installation for a folder called DDEDemo. It's a DDE project that Delphi use to ship with (I'm not 100% sure it's still included, but have a look). The demo includes a DDE client and server.

Edit - Try this [link](http://ftp.sunet.se/delphi/ftp/d10free/ddedemo.zip) for some example code.

Comment: Wow.. that's D1! (perhaps also D2, but not D3). You've got quite a memory.. Compiles with D2007, not sure if they work as intended though.

Comment: that demo covers only the client part.

Comment: @Sertac I use D1 daily to learn Pascal. Can't afford a new version yet though XE Starter looks good.

Comment: Anyone know if it's okay to provide hikari with the demo source from D1?

Comment: @Frank - Wondered about the same but don't know. @hikari - [This thread](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=50123&tstart=1) on embarcadero forums has two links to demo code by 'Peter Below'.

Answer (score 2):

It is so easy to use the DDE server that you don't even need sample code.  You can do it just at designtime inside the Delphi form designer:

To create a server that sends out data:

1. Drop a TDDEServerConv and
   TDDEServerItem on your form or data
   module.
2. Connect the server item to
   the server conversation (set
   DDEServerItem1.ServerConv=DdeServerConv1
   using object inspector, there is a
   drop down list, but double clicking
   it is enough).
3. Set the DDEServerItem.Text value to some valid text value (ie 'A')

To receive data, you might want to have macros that are executed by the DDE client that pass data to the server. For this you use the DdeServerConv.OnExecuteMacro event.  Try dumping the parameter Msg:TStrings to a memo like this:

```
  Memo1.Lines.Assign(Msg);
```

Now save and run your project.

To test it in excel type in:

```
=Project1|DdeServerConv1!DdeServerItem1
```

The excel dde client syntax parts are Application name followed by vertical bar, conversation name, followed by exclamation mark, then item name.

And you will see the value (A, or whatever you put into the Text property in the item) appear in Excel.

That's a working single item DDE server without any code written by you.

I generally find that I create the conversations and the items at runtime, instead of at designtime, in a real world scenario that is more useful for me.

For older (non unicode) Delphi versions there is also a full featured commercial product called Django that helps a lot with DDE work.

I think also you might be looking for information on how to write a "DDE Poke" command handler on the delphi side. I don't have a demo for that.  I tried it, and the obvious things didn' quite work right for me (the item on your server has an OnPoke event, I wrote a simple client, called PokeData, and it didn't work).

Comment: Hi, cant get this to work. I dont know how to use DDE in Excel, but I made a little client tester app. For example, this works with mIRC: http://pastebin.com/pqhLuZWN I can succesfully retrieve data from mIRC like nickname etc. I tried to use this with a server test app the way you tell me, but it never shows anything in the Memo. Also, how would you specify the DDE Service name in the server?

Comment: If you tried it and it didn't work, you either gave the wrong server name, topic name, or item name. Those are the only three reasonable possibilities. It's not as hard as you think.  You see what I said above? The server name of my project was Project1. The conversation name is DdeServerConv1, and the Item is DDeServerItem1.